# How to center a TikZ tree in a Beamer slide?

Tags: beamer, tikz-trees, trees, beamer-metropolis

I created a tikz tree inside a Beamer slide, using the following code:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=54, 10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e,mathtools,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}

\metroset{block=fill}
\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\justifying

\title{Probabilité}
\subtitle{Probabilité Conditionnelle}
\date[]{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Correction Exercice 5}
    On peut représenter cette situation dans le diagramme suivant, avec les événements \alert{$S$: Le candidat tire l'épreuve de statistique} et \alert{$R$: Le candidat réussit le concours}.
% Set the overall layout of the tree
    \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=2.5cm, sibling distance=3cm]
    \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=1.7cm]
    % Define styles for bags and leafs
    \tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=4em, text centered]
    \tikzstyle{end} = [circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[ sloped]
            \node[circle, draw] {}
                child {
                    node[bag] {$S$}        
                        child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(R|S)=1/3$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$R$}
                            node[below]  {}
                             }
                        child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(\overline{R}|S)$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$\overline{R}$}
                            node[below]  {}
                            }
                            edge from parent 
                            node[above] {}
                            node[below]  {}
                    }
                child {
                    node[bag] {$E_2$}        
                    child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(R|E_2)$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$R$}
                            node[below]  {}
                             }
                        child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(\overline{R}|E_2)$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$\overline{R}$}
                            node[below]  {}
                            }
                    edge from parent         
                        node[above] {}
                        node[below]  {}
                }
                child {
                    node[bag] {$E_3$}        
                    child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(R|E_3)$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$R$}
                            node[below]  {}
                             }
                        child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(\overline{R}|E_3)$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$\overline{R}$}
                            node[below]  {}
                            }
                    edge from parent         
                        node[above] {}
                        node[below]  {}
                }
                child {
                    node[bag] {$E_4$}        
                    child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(R|E_4)$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$R$}
                            node[below]  {}
                             }
                        child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(\overline{R}|E_4)$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$\overline{R}$}
                            node[below]  {}
                            }
                    edge from parent         
                        node[above] {}
                        node[below]  {}
                }
                ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But the tree is not completely inside the slide:

[image]

How do I make the tree perfectly centered and visible inside the slide? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your image is to wide that it can be centered on frame. Consequently it spill out of right frame border. Make it narrower (for example with  use of the smaller  labels font).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a quick hack to temporarily get more room, you could use the beamer `columns` environment, which will effectively remove the text margins:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=54, 10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e,mathtools,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\justifying

\title{Probabilité}
\subtitle{Probabilité Conditionnelle}
\date[]{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Correction Exercice 5}
    On peut représenter cette situation dans le diagramme suivant, avec les événements \alert{$S$: Le candidat tire l'épreuve de statistique} et \alert{$R$: Le candidat réussit le concours}.
% Set the overall layout of the tree
    \tikzset{
      level 1/.style={level distance=2.5cm, sibling distance=3cm},
      level 2/.style={level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=1.7cm},
      bag/.style={text width=4em, text centered},
      end/.style={circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt}
    }
    \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{\paperwidth}
    \centering
    \small
        \begin{tikzpicture}[sloped]
            \node[circle, draw] {}
                child {
                    node[bag] {$S$}        
                        child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(R|S)=1/3$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$R$}
                            node[below]  {}
                             }
                        child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(\overline{R}|S)$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$\overline{R}$}
                            node[below]  {}
                            }
                            edge from parent 
                            node[above] {}
                            node[below]  {}
                    }
                child {
                    node[bag] {$E_2$}        
                    child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(R|E_2)$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$R$}
                            node[below]  {}
                             }
                        child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(\overline{R}|E_2)$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$\overline{R}$}
                            node[below]  {}
                            }
                    edge from parent         
                        node[above] {}
                        node[below]  {}
                }
                child {
                    node[bag] {$E_3$}        
                    child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(R|E_3)$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$R$}
                            node[below]  {}
                             }
                        child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(\overline{R}|E_3)$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$\overline{R}$}
                            node[below]  {}
                            }
                    edge from parent         
                        node[above] {}
                        node[below]  {}
                }
                child {
                    node[bag] {$E_4$}        
                    child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(R|E_4)$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$R$}
                            node[below]  {}
                             }
                        child {
                            node[end, label=below:
                                {$P(\overline{R}|E_4)$}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$\overline{R}$}
                            node[below]  {}
                            }
                    edge from parent         
                        node[above] {}
                        node[below]  {}
                }
                ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer works perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: @SaïdMaanan You're welcome!

Comment: You should told to OP that `\tikzstyle˙  for determining of nodes styles is obsolete and that (s)he should use `tikzset` or options of picture instead.

Comment: @Zarko Good point! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I would redraw your image as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Correction Exercice 5}
    On peut représenter cette situation dans le diagramme suivant, avec les événements \alert{$S$: Le candidat tire l'épreuve de statistique} et \alert{$R$: Le candidat réussit le concours}.
% Set the overall layout of the tree
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[sloped,
every label/.append style = {font=\scriptsize, text width=3em, align=center},
%
           level distance = 22mm, 
           level 1/.style = {sibling distance=24mm},
           level 2/.style = {sibling distance=12mm},   
    bag/.style = {text width=4em, text centered},
    end/.style = {circle, minimum width=3pt, fill, inner sep=0pt}
                            ]
\node[circle, draw] {}
    child { node[bag]    {$S$}
        child { node[end,label=below: {$P(R|S)$ $=1/3$}] {}
                    edge from parent node[above] {$R$}}
        child { node[end,label=below: {$P(\bar{R}|S)$}] {}
                    edge from parent node[above] {$\bar{R}$}
                }
            }
    child { node[bag]    {$E_2$}
        child { node[end,label=below: {$P(R|E_2)$}] {}
                    edge from parent node[above] {$R$}}
        child { node[end,label=below: {$P(\bar{R}|E_2)$}] {}
                    edge from parent node[above] {$\bar{R}$}
                }
            }
    child { node[bag]    {$E_3$}
        child { node[end,label=below: {$P(R|E_3)$}] {}
                    edge from parent node[above] {$R$}}
        child { node[end,label=below: {$P(\bar{R}|E_3)$}] {}
                    edge from parent node[above] {$\bar{R}$}
                }
            }
    child { node[bag]    {$E_4$}
        child { node[end,label=below: {$P(R|E_4)$}] {}
                    edge from parent node[above] {$R$}}
        child { node[end,label=below: {$P(\bar{R}|E_4)$}] {}
                    edge from parent node[above] {$\bar{R}$}
                }
            }
%
            ;             
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]